# Looping two arrays and combining data

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, vuex

I am trying to figure out the best way to do something.  Essentially, I allow for CSVs to be uploaded.  When this happens, I store the state of an upload within an array e.g.

```
tempAttachments:Array[2]
  0:Object
    _id:"12345-678910"
    bytes:412051
    file:File
    size:411532
    title:"someFile.csv"
    type:"file"
    fileType:"typeOne"
  1:Object
    _id:"9999-2222"
    bytes:12345
    file:File
    size:23456
    title:"anotherFile.csv"
    type:"file"
    fileType:"typeTwo"
```

When these files are confirmed and submitted, I read the first five lines are return their data.  So I know what lines belong to which file, I set the key to the `fileType`.

The data that is returned looks something like this

```
data:
  0: 
    typeOne: 
      0: ["123", "21/11/2013", "10"]
      1: ["234", "22/11/2013", "20"]
      2: ["345", "12/09/2018", "100"]
      3: ["456", "22/03/2016", "350"]
      4: ["567", "13/02/2013", "50"]
```

So that is the first five rows for the file with the fileType typeOne.  What I am now trying to do is add this array to the appropiate array element in `tempAttachments`.

So I have my function which takes the data array.  I then assume I have to loop the attachments array, and inside this loop the data array.  Then I need to get the keys, and loop these to see if there is a match.  This is what I have so far

```
createFileData (state, data) {
  for (const attachment of state.tempAttachments) {
    for (const fileData of data) {
      for (const key of Object.keys(fileData)) {
        if (key === attachment.fileType) {
          console.log('Match')
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see it is not very gracious.  So my question is whether I can do this in a more elegant way using ES6?  Additionally, what would be the best way to then add the data to my attachments array?  I have been playing around with the spread operator but not fully grasped it yet.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can try like this

```js
createFileData (state, data) 
{
  const types = {}; // our hashmap

  // collect all unique types
  data.forEach(item =>
  {
    Object.keys(item).forEach(key =>
    {
      types[key] = true;
    });
  });

  state.tempAttachments.forEach(attachment =>
  {
    if (attachment.fileType in types)
    {
      console.log('Match')
    }
  });
}
```

---

## Adding new data

```js
createFileData (state, data) 
{
  data.forEach(item =>
  {
    Object.entries(item).forEach((type, rows) =>
    {
      rows.forEach(row =>
      {
        state.tempAttachments.push({
          fileType: type,
          documentID: row[0],
          documentDate: row[1],
          documentAmount: row[2],
        });
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, seems to work well.  What would the process be to actually add the data to the tempAttachments array?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different approach if you would like to try it

```js
  tempAttachments=[
  {
    _id:"12345-678910",
    bytes:412051,
    file:'File',
    size:411532,
    title:"someFile.csv",
    type:"file",
    fileType:"typeOne",
  },
  {
    _id:"9999-2222",
    bytes:12345,
    file:'File',
    size:23456,
    title:"anotherFile.csv",
    type:"file",
    fileType:"typeTwo"
  }
  ]
  data={
typeOne:{
  0: ["123", "21/11/2013", "10"],
  1: ["234", "22/11/2013", "20"],
  2: ["345", "12/09/2018", "100"],
  3: ["456", "22/03/2016", "350"],
  4: ["567", "13/02/2013", "50"]
 }
} 

     
tempAttachments.forEach(o=>{Object.entries(data).forEach(y=>{ if(o.fileType==y[0]) Object.assign(o,{[y[0]]:y})})})
console.log(tempAttachments)
```